# StackOverflowError: stack size 16KB

Tags: android, multithreading, android-source

I am facing "StackOverflowError: stack size 16KB" in Android 5.1.1 version when an application tries to create thread of stack size "1024000". Below is the crash message.

But this issue is gone when the stack size is rounded up by 1024. (1025024). In the below example ***m_uStackSize*** is the stack size.

I tried to debug the thread calls in libc.so. But no clues so far. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Please use below link for backtracking log.

[1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycrj7yrbnux3vrl/backtrace.log?dl=0) attachments

Edit 1:

```
pthread_attr_t     threadAttr;

struct sched_param schedParams;

VPTYPE_RETURN      result;



pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);



pthread_attr_setstacksize(&threadAttr, m_uStackSize);

pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&threadAttr, SCHED_OTHER);



int priMax = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_OTHER);

int priMin = sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_OTHER);



schedParams.sched_priority = priMin + (((255 - m_uPriority) * (priMax - priMin)) / 255);

pthread_attr_setschedparam(&threadAttr, &schedParams);



result = pthread_create(&m_threadHandle, &threadAttr, (void*(*)(void*))staticEntryPoint, this);



pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttr);
```

One more thing to be noted. I am developing BSP for Android Device. This code sample is from application, which runs with no issues with other standard Android devices and mobiles.

So issue seems with BSP,from the crash messages I can see it is in libc.

Stack Trace

gnal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

Abort message: 'art/runtime/thread.cc:1106] No pending exception expected: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 16KB'

r0 00000000  r1 00000643  r2 00000006  r3 00000000

r4 a3305db8  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c

r8 00000001  r9 b4f4f550  sl a3b13400  fp a3b34900

ip 00000643  sp a3305310  lr b6e98fc1  pc b6ebbe58  cpsr 60070010

backtrace:

00 pc 00039e58  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)

01 pc 00016fbd  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)

02 pc 00017bcf  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)

03 pc 0001439d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)

04 pc 00012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)

05 pc 00226033  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+170)

06 pc 000a72e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)

07 pc 0025629d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::GetQuickInvokedMethod(art::Instruction const*, art::verifier::RegisterLine*, bool)+280)

08 pc 0025a66b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::VerifyInvokeVirtualQuickArgs(art::Instruction const*, bool)+50)

09 pc 0025e7c3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::CodeFlowVerifyInstruction(unsigned int*)+4918)

10 pc 00260323  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::CodeFlowVerifyMethod()+142)

11 pc 002607c7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::VerifyCodeFlow()+614)

12 pc 0026093f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::Verify()+130)

13 pc 00261feb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::verifier::MethodVerifier::FindLocksAtDexPc(art::mirror::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, std::__1::vector

14 pc 001f41e5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Monitor::VisitLocks(art::StackVisitor*, void (*)(art::mirror::Object*, void*), void*, bool)+252)

15 pc 00233a07  /system/lib/libart.so (art::StackDumpVisitor::VisitFrame()+374)

16 pc 0022dbeb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::StackVisitor::WalkStack(bool)+702)

17 pc 002361c9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) const+224)

18 pc 0023f31d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpLocked(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)+120)

19 pc 00225d91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)+272)

20 pc 00225fdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+82)

21 pc 000a72e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)

22 pc 00233d85  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingException() const+396)

23 pc 0023940d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreatePeer(char const*, bool, _jobject*)+456)

24 pc 0023a265  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Attach(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+236)

25 pc 00223309  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::AttachCurrentThread(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+16)

26 pc 001bccf1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JII::AttachCurrentThread(_JavaVM*, _JNIEnv**, void*)+216)

27 pc 000c0773  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJII::AttachCurrentThread(_JavaVM*, _JNIEnv**, void*)+110)

28 pc 00039865  /data/app/us.my.test.app-1/lib/arm/libXyclops.so (VPThreadInfo::entryPoint()+36)

29 pc 000398c3  /data/app/us.my.test.app-1/lib/arm/libXyclops.so (VPThreadInfo::staticEntryPoint(void*)+6)

30 pc 0001674b  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)

31 pc 000146fb  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)

Comment: Post some code please, as it currently is - your question isn't very clear. Stacktrace also helps.

Comment: Please put the stacktrace here, not link to other sites, including DropBox.

Comment: We still wait code

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have added the code  and stacktrace.

Comment: More information related to this issue. This issue is only occurring in Engineering build of AOSP. For user build and user-debug build, this issue is not happening.